# What approach to take to make my code more generic Java/ Spring?

Tags: java, spring, generics, design-patterns, autowired

In a `SpringBoot` application I have a service (in the Spring sense) that calls clients that themselves consume RestFul web services by calling a function that is identical to `createXXX` except that the nature of the object changes at the input of the method.
To simplify, let's suppose that I model the creation of animals: with the objects `CatDTO`, `DogDTO`, `HorseDTO` as input of the web services. `AnimaslDTO` is an object composed of different types of animals (there is no inheritance relationship).

I make the three clients in the same manner let's take the cat's example

```
package com.animals.client;
import ...

@Service
public class CatClient {

    private static final String CODE_WS_CREATE_CAT = "createCat";
    /**
     * Call RestFul WS for Cat Creation
     * @param catDTO
     */
    public ResponseEntity<String> createCat(CatDTO catDTO)
    {
        // ... Call a RestFul WS in the same manner for each animal. Only the parameter change in each client
        // --> ie dogDTO in DogClient.createDog, HorseDTO in HorseClient.createHorse,
    }
}
```

In AnimalService implemented by `AnimalServiceImpl` I try to create the three animals
Here is the code

```
package com.animals.service.impl;

import ...

@Service
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {

    @Autowired
    private CatClient catClient;

    @Autowired
    private DogClient dogClient;

    @Autowired
    private HorseClient horseClient;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> createAnimals(AnimalsDTO animalsDTO) {
        catClient.createCat(animalsDTO.getCat());
        dogClient.createDog(animalsDTO.getDog());
        horseClient.createHorse(animalsDTO.getHorse());
        .... 
    }
}
```

I want to know how to generify my clients in Spring or Java for the methods which are very similar to `createXXX`. What design pattern can I use?  What I've tried is to use Java generics but it doesn't fit well with Spring. I've tried to create an `AnimalClient(T)` class where T is the animal but I have problems in autowiring constructor with one argument.

Thanks by advance!

Comment: Can you add AnimalsDTO? And one from CatDTO or DogDTO?

Comment: I would argue that generics work great here. Nevertheless, have you looked at a factory or an adapter?

Comment: Take a look on generics : https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Comment: @MehulGayate I've taken "Animals" case to simplify my use case and make it easier to understand. In reality I work with many composite objects

Comment: @askappy  The problem that I encountered with generics is the following : OK I created AnimalClient<T> and so the only way to instanciate the generic type T was to define it in a one argument constructor. But when I was defining my three "real animal" client components in the AnimalServiceImpl I coudn't autowire three constructors AnimalClient<CatClient> AnimalClient<DogClient>, AnimalClient<HorseClient> because these three constructor will be in confict. Perharps there is a smart way to do it with Spring but I don't know it. Design patterns as factory seem complicated for my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have `Inheritance`, you cannot solve this efficiently even if you try to use `Generics`

Here is one way to simplify your code:

`BaseAnimalDto` is a marker interface for now. You can common methods here if you want.

```
public interface BaseAnimalDTO {

}
```

`CatDTO`

```
public class CatDTO implements BaseAnimalDTO {
    // Cat DTO code
}
```

Create a `BaseAnimalClient` as follows

```
public interface BaseAnimalClient {

    ResponseEntity<String> create(BaseAnimalDTO dto);
}
```

`CatClient` looks like this

```
@Service
public class CatClient implements BaseAnimalClient {

    private static final String CODE_WS_CREATE_CAT = "createCat";

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(BaseAnimalDTO dto) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Let's create a universal `AnimalClient` like this:

```
@Service
public class AnimalClient implements BaseAnimalClient {

    @Autowired
    private CatClient catClient;

    @Autowired
    private DogClient dogClient;

    @Autowired
    private HorseClient horseClient;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(BaseAnimalDTO dto) {
        BaseAnimalClient client;
        if (dto instanceof CatDTO) {
            client = catClient;
        } else if (dto instanceof DogDTO) {
            client = dogClient;
        } else {
            client = horseClient;
        }
        return client.create(dto);
    }
}
```

Now, your `AnimalServiceImpl` looks like this

```
@Service
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {

    @Autowired
    private AnimalClient animalClient;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> createAnimals(AnimalsDTO animalsDTO) {
        animalClient.create(animalsDTO.getCat());
        animalClient.create(animalsDTO.getDog());
        animalClient.create(animalsDTO.getHorse());
        .... 
    }
}
```

However, if you can modify your `AnimalsDTO` like this:

```
public class AnimalsDTO {

    private List<? extends BaseAnimalDTO> animalDtos;

    // getter, setters

}
```

Then, your `AnimalServiceImpl` will be more simplified like this:

```
@Service
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {

    @Autowired
    private AnimalClient animalClient;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> createAnimals(AnimalsDTO animalsDTO) {
        for (BaseAnimalDTO animalDTO : animalsDTO.getAnimalDtos()) {
            animalClient.create(animalDTO);
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Fine ! It's a simple and clear approach, the one I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped. kindly mark the answer if it solved your problem. thanks